# How to convert an unsigned decimal (less than 1<<32) to 4 bytes (binary) in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, binary, floating-point

Example:

```
$ decimal=$(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 ))
$ echo $decimal
$ printf "%08x" $decimal | xxd -r -p >bytes
```

The result is in `bytes` file.

Can it be done in a single command without unnecessary conversion to hex first?

Comment: related: [Send data as bytes to pipe in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11128226/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `perl`:

```perl
$ perl -e 'print pack "I>", shift' $(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 ))
```

Comment: +1. It looks like it always produces 4 bytes and it is a single command. Why do you use `shift` instead of `$ARGV[0]` or similar?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It's shorter, easy typing and more idiom.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `printf` builtin to emit bytes given by octal codes.

```
x=1193046
printf "$(printf "\\%03o" $((x>>24&255)) $((x>>16&255)) $((x>>8&255)) $((x&255)))"
```

Comment: +1. It produces the correct 4 bytes for 0..2**32-1 range,  It uses only builtin `printf` command, and It is faster (for a single number).

Answer (score 1):

`dc` can take an arbitrary input radix and output on an equally arbitrary output radix. You communicate with `dc` by handing it first a value *(or string of values separated by whitespace)* and next a command for handling the value. `dc` defaults to a base 10 radix for both input and output.

For example, to convert arbitrary decimal values to binary *(or, at least, to base 2)*:

```
printf 2o%dp "'A" | dc
1000001
```

That works out to the following list of commands for `dc`:

1. add 2 to the top of the main stack
2. pop the top value from the main stack and use its value as the `o`utput radix
3. add 65 *(the ASCII decimal value of A as converted by `printf` in my locale)* to the top of the main stack
4. pop the top value from the main stack and `p` rint its value to `stdout` in the base currently specified as the output radix

`dc` will also print ASCII values for bytes as interpreted by its input radix:

```
printf 8i%oP "'A" | dc
A
```

...and...

```
printf 2i%sP 1000001 | dc
A
```

The process is much the same as before except that `i` is used to specify the `i`nput radix as opposed to the previous `o`utput radix and that `P` is used to interpret the top stack value as an ASCII character on output.

`bc` can do much of the same, though it tends to much more verbose syntax. Do `man dc` and `man bc` for more. bitwise shifts are not in either program's repertoire, though. Still, as you have shown, any POSIX shell can handle that end with arithmetic expansion fairly easily.

Comment: I don't see how `dc` converts a decimal number e.g., `1193046` to 4 bytes as the code in my question and the other two answers does.